# How to convert string to list such as: [foo(a,b),a,b,c,d]

Tags: python, string, list

I like to convert a given string that contains a substring such as 'foo(a,b)' for e.g: the string can be `"foo(a,b),a,b,c,d"` or `"a,b,c,foo(a,b)"` or `"a,b,foo(a,b),c,d"` in a list.

```
stripped = s.replace(" ", "")
new_list = stripped.split(",")
```

#This is my code that and I am only removing all white spaces and splitting the string

Expected output:

```
['foo(a,b)','a','b','c','d'] or ['a','b','c','foo(a,b)','d'] or ['a','b','c','d','foo(a,b)']
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what exact formats you're working with, but have you tried simply doing `s.split()`?

Comment: you mean you have string as `"foo(a,b), a, b , c, d"` and you want it to be converted as list of substrings as `["foo(a,b)", "a", "b", "c", "d"]` ? If yes, then you can do: `s.split(", ")`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I have the string as format "foo(a,b),a,b,c,d" without spaces

Comment: still you haven't clarified your question

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri when I was trying to convert my string "f(a,b),b,c,d" into a list using type casting it to list I was getting the result as: [f,o,o,(,a,b,),a,b,c,d,] which was not what I wanted. And I assumed doing split(',') will split the foo(a,b) as well which I didn't want either. Well you were right !! and split("," ) is working to split my string by commas into a list

Comment: Do you want a list of strings, or do you want a list of the results of evaluating `foo(a, b)` etc?  You don't have `""` around the items so it's unclear.

Answer (score 1):

A regex seems like the easiest way to go:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("[^,]*\(.*\)[^,]*|[^,]+", s)
['foo(a,b)', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

For anything more complex you might want to look at an actual language parser.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't so clear, specially your posted code.

If the original string is "foo(a,b),a,b,c,d" without spaces, using split(",") creates a list as ['foo(a', 'b)', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].

The solution is totally hardcoded so I don't like it...

my proposal is:

> s = "foo(a,b),a,b,c,d"
>
> stripped = s.split(",")
>
> combo = stripped[0] + "," + stripped[1]
> stripped.remove(stripped[0])
> stripped.remove(stripped[0])
> stripped.insert(0,combo)
> print (stripped)

Comment: foo(a,b) can occur anywhere in the string